# ActivityScenario: Activity has been destroyed already

Tags: java, android, android-studio, testing

AndroidX's `ActivityScenario` API seems to destroy the activity starightaway:

I have been trying to move my Robolectic test cases to Android X Test. I've followed the documentation but unable to launch the activity through Activity Scenario Launch API.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario

http://robolectric.org/androidx_test

```
protected void setupActivity() {
      ActivityScenario<VisitorExemptionActivity> scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(VisitorExemptionActivity.class);
        scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.CREATED);// Activity destroyed before reaching to this point.
}
```

Above code does not call any android life cycle except onStart , throw following exception and destroyed the activity straight away.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot move to state "CREATED" since
> the Activity has been destroyed already

When I tried the same code with Robolectric. It work fine and call all life Cycle. oncreate , onstart and onResume.

```
protected void setupActivity() {
activityController = Robolectric.buildActivity(VisitorExemptionActivity.class).setup();
activityController.get();
}
```

Above code call all the life cycle.

Please can you explain to me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, where after some debugging and testing the "tests":

- `onActivity` is called after my Activity's `onCreate(...)`.
- Said `onCreate(...)` launches a background-thread, which based on conditions, would call said Activity's `finish()`.
- Finally, `onActivity` is never called if the Activity's `finish()` is called before it.

The error may say "destroyed", but `onActivity`'s docs say that it even throws if Activity's "finishing" or "finished".

Which was a surprise, as my test was all about checking if `finish()` is called after setting the right property of the Activity.

### Solutions

Solution A; I un-deprecated `ActivityTestRule`, which as you may already know, is no big deal and is what the well known AndroidX library does all the time for Android's API (not it's own API).

Get **`ActivityTestRule.java`** file from:
https://gist.github.com/top-master/2127623cd837df9a9633714c44a56e16

Solution B; in your Activity add and use something like:

```
protected void finishSafely() {
    if (MyApp.isTestRun()) {
        MyApp.triggerTestHook("MyActivity:finishing");
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

> Where you need to decide how to implement `isTestRun()` and `triggerTestHook(...)` methods (where their names explain what they do).